# Фрикативный звук [г] в слове бухгалтер

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

По некоторым данным, слово *бухгалтер* имеет два варианта произношения: с традиционным для фонетической системы русского языка взрывным [г] и с фрикативным [γ], характерным для украинского. Почему? Ведь здесь речь об ассимиляции не идёт, так как [х] и [г] в русском языке не имеют ничего общего...

Comment: может играет роль немецкого языка, из которого это слово вышло: Buchhalter, где Buch -> книга. Здесь звук тоже фрикативный, как в ach а не мягкий как в ich

Answer (score 1):

В слове ***бухгалтер*** произносится звук h согласно словарям. В Интернете можно найти такое описание этого звука: [Как правильно произносить слово "бухгалтер­"? | bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1089902-kak-pravilno-proiznosit-slovo-buhgalter.html)

"Звук [h] – это Г фрикативный, нечто среднее между звуками [г] и [х]. В древнерусском языке этот звук был нормой во многих словах, но со временем он был заменён взрывным [г], произношение которого стало нормированным.

Сохранился Г фрикативный в южнорусских говорах, а также в других языках восточнославянской ветви (к ней относится и русский язык) славянских языков: украинском и белорусском. Вместе с тем и в языке русском существует несколько лексем, нормой в которых является произношение Г фрикативного (ага, ого, господи)".

И по поводу того, что  [х] и [г] в русском языке не имеют ничего общего.

Звуки Г, К, Х составляют группу заднеязычных согласных с одним местом образования, но разными способами образования. Г и К – взрывные, Х – фрикативный. Тогда Г фрикативный – это звонкий вариант фрикативного глухого Х.

Comment: Спасибо, я превосходно знаю, что [г] (фрикативный) и [х] составляют пару по звонкости-глухости в, к примеру, украинском языке. Меня интересует другое: почему такой звук, в общем-то несвойственный русскому языку, возникает в этом слове вопреки всем нормам произношения.

Comment: Вы всё прочитали в ответе? Там сказано, что в древнерусском языке этот звук БЫЛ нормой во многих словах, поэтому он НЕ ВОЗНИКАЕТ, а просто в некоторых словах СОХРАНИЛСЯ. И что значит "вопреки всем нормам произношения"?  Такое произношение является нормированным и соответствует орфоэпическим словарям. Поэтому мне не очень понятна  логика Ваших рассуждений. Если же  Вы считает эту информацию неверной, то Вам, вероятно, следует задать этот вопрос на специализированных сайтах, где можно получить ответ от специалистов по исторической фонетике.

Comment: Фрикативный звук «сохранился»? Он мог «сохраниться» в словах типа Господь, благо и проч., берущих начало в древнерусском языке, но уж никак не в таком относительно позднем заимствовании. Спасибо, к специалистам обращусь.

Comment: Обращаться к специалистам - это единственно правильное решение, надо их только найти, а потом ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО выслушать и правильно понять   ответ. К примеру, я говорю, что  звук сохранился в некоторых словах, то есть он сохранился в языке, но не говорю, что он сохранился в слове бухгалтер (там он просто использовался, возможно, для передачи сочетания букв ХГ), а вы домысливаете, что сохранился именно в слове бухгалтер. Это пример того, что ответ понят неправильно. В любом случае, желаю Вам удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Бу**хг**алтер.
Здесь буква *г* делает звонкой предшествующую *х*, ср.: [делать] - [зьделать], [бухгалтер] - [буhгалтер].
А т.к. в русском языке очень трудной произнести буквосочетание *hг*, то оно сливается в *hh*: **[буhалтир]**.